# Python Download Files from Sharepoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint

I saw this: [Python - Download files from SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671547/python-download-files-from-sharepoint-site)

But it does not work for me. I am getting the following error:

```
assertion_node = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion", 'Assertion')[0].toxml()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code I am using, what am I doing wrong?

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

url = """https://my_url.sharepoint.com/location/AllItems.aspx?otherstuff"""


username = "here_is_my_username"
password = "here_is_my_pw"


ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password) <---this is where it errors out at
ctx = ClientContext(url,ctx_auth)
```

**Edit #1:**

The clue is somewhere in here:

```
'saml': '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion}',
```

That line isn't populated for some reason....the question is, how do I populate it and with what? It comes from the saml_token_provider.py file when you install these libraries:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
```