# Using python to recursively download files from SharePoint site

Tags: python, sharepoint, scripting

Has anyone been able to recursively download files from a SharePoint site using python? I want to download, basically, an entire folder structure and all of the files, primarily image files (.jpg, .png), and store them on desktop.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: There is already another question similar to this from where you can start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671547/python-download-files-from-sharepoint-site

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I will start there.