# downlad file from sharepoint via python error: The access policy does not allow token issuance

Tags: python, sharepoint

I was looking [Python - Download files from SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671547/python-download-files-from-sharepoint-site) to try and download files from sharepoint, but I get this error:

```
ValueError: An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.
```

I contacted my It team, and they said `alter your Python script to use Modern Authentication rather than Legacy Authentication`

does anyone know what a more modern authentication method is to download files from Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the **Client credentials** instead of the user credentials. You may have to follow the steps in the following GitHub link to obtain the secret.

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/wiki/How-to-connect-to-SharePoint-Online-and-and-SharePoint-2013-2016-2019-on-premises--with-app-principal

Copying the sourcecode from the above just for reference:

```
client_id = "--client id goes here--"
client_secret = "-- secret goes here--"
site_url = "https://example.sharepoint.com/"

from office365.runtime.auth.Client_Credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext


creds = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(creds)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
```