# I can't get the folders from my sharepoint site, how can i resolve this?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, office365-rest-client

I'm currently using a python program to convert documents to store in a databse. For this I need to access sharepoint sites and download the neccesary files.

I've been using multiple tutorials and examples dealing with the office365 REST py library but whatever I try I can't even seem to be able to see the folders that i want to work with.

The code I am currently running

```py
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.client_request_exception import ClientRequestException


site_url = "https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/<my_site_name>"



ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("user","pass")   
ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)


folder_rel_url = "/sites/<my_site_name>/Data/<myFolder>"
folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_rel_url).select("Exists").get().execute_query()
if folder.exists:
    print("Folder is found")
else:
    print("Folder not found")


def try_get_folder(url):
    try:
        return ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(url).get().execute_query()
    except ClientRequestException as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 404:
            return None
        else:
            raise ValueError(e.response.text)
```

The homepage link of the sharepoint site = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/<my_site_name>"

[image: site makeup]

I've tried multiple solutions including: [Python - Download files from SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671547/python-download-files-from-sharepoint-site)
This solution simply gave me an empty return {} when changing the variables exactly as told in the tutorial

I've also tried changing the urls:
/sites/<my_site_name>/Shared%20Documents/
/sites/<my_site_name>/Start/Data
etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the technology I specialize in is the Microsoft Graph API, which also encapsulates endpoints for [accessing SharePoint sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http): `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}`
and [downloading files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=httpt): `GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content`, I would recommend using the Microsoft Graph API.

To use the graph Api, you first need to authenticate and acquire a token, which contains the permissions required to use a specific endpoint, and you need to register your app in AD partial and add permissions to it.

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0) to follow the complete guidance.

Hope this helps. If you need any more help, please feel free to comment below. Best Wishes.